# How to Create a joint (b2RevoluteJoint, b2MouseJoint, b2WeldJoint etc) using GBox2D (cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have read a nice tutorial [MonkeyJump](http://www.raywenderlich.com/7261/monkey-jump) where Andreas Loew show, how to make a physics game using TexturePacker, PhysicsEditor and GBox2D.

My question is, how to create a joint (b2RevoluteJoint, b2MouseJoint, b2WeldJoint etc) using GBox2D. I have learn to create these joints using box2d, but i am not sure, how to make it using GBox2D.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas Loew states joints are not yet implemented in GBox2d. Here is the github link for it:

[GBox2d @ Github](https://github.com/AndreasLoew/GBox2D)

In the readme it says "It's not yet complete - e.g. joints are not yet supported."

Cya